# Integration iPhone app with Facebook Twitter TwitPic and more

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, twitter, social-networking

It's not a code question.
I've found a nice tool online few months ago and now I cannot remember it's name/address. Maybe you know.

I've found a great sample application integrating most of the social services - Facebook, twitter, TwitPic, myspace and so on.

So you only had to add few classes to your project, fill the appIDs, sercret codes and you were ready to use all of them (with a standard UI) without spending countless hours implementing every single one on my own.

Maybe you remember where I can find this app? It was great.

regards
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be thinking of ShareKit. It can be found at this URL: [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/)

I have found ShareKit very easy to use.

Comment: Sharekit is the worst ever iOs library.

Answer (score 1):

Czest,

I found this..http://three20.info/ hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://www.gigya.com/social-login/ , i think this is the best option to date.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of UIImagePicker replacements out there that support loading photos from other services:

GrabKit is an iOS Objective-C library offering simple and unified methods to retrieve photo albums on Facebook, Flickr, Picasa, iPhone/iPad and Instagram

https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit

Photo Picker+ a new free library for iOS that replaces the native photo chooser to let users select a photo from Facebook, Picasa, Flickr, or Instagram, in addition to the local Camera Roll or Photo Stream.

http://picture.io/photopickerplus